# Load Balancer to IIS timeout

Tags: iis, timeout, load-balancing

IIS has a timeout set for 120 seconds (2 minutes). but the Load Balancer considers a box unhealthy after 90 seconds (load balancer health check timeout = 90 sec), so there is a possibility this is contributing to outages because the unresponsive requests immediately cause the Load Balancer to pull the boxes from the pool.

Now question is, What is the appropriate combination for IIS timeout to Load balancer health check timeout. Should i keep this same period or what should it be set ideally?

Thanks and appreciate any response on this